# WebActivatorEx.dll (Unity bootstrap) is firing on a different project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have 3/4 projects all using their own Unity, with a bootstrap.cs file, these are from the Unity Mvc5 nuget package.

When I start project 1, namespace (MvcAdmin)
it is firing the bootstrap for project 2 (namespace MvcApi), which is causing an exception!

I've checked and confirmed it's not caused by iis routes or anything. Also checked, all WebActivatorEx's are using different namespaces etc.

This class below is what is firing, but it shouldn't be:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MvcApi.App_Start.UnityWebApiActivator), "Start")]

namespace MvcApi.App_Start
{
    /// <summary>Provides the bootstrapping for integrating Unity with WebApi when it is hosted in ASP.NET</summary>
    public static class UnityWebApiActivator
    {
        /// <summary>Integrates Unity when the application starts.</summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            // Use UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver if you want to use a new child container for each IHttpController resolution.
            // var resolver = new UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());

            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
            DepResolver.SetResolver(new DepResolver(container));
            DepResolver.ExceptionHelper().OnAppInit();

            var resolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;

        }
    }
}
```

Why could this be happening?

Here's my callstack:

```
MvcShared.dll!MvcShared.Helpers.AppSettingsHelper.throwExceptionIfCountIncorrect(int count) Line 129    C#
    MvcShared.dll!MvcShared.Helpers.AppSettingsHelper.GetAppSettingsFromDb() Line 109 + 0x3c bytes  C#
    MvcShared.dll!MvcShared.Helpers.AppSettingsHelper.ReadXmlAndStoreSettings() Line 48 + 0xa bytes C#
>   MvcApi.dll!MvcApi.App_Start.UnityConfig.RegisterTypes(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container) + 0x774 bytes    
    MvcApi.dll!MvcApi.App_Start.UnityConfig..cctor.AnonymousMethod__0() + 0x65 bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Lazy<Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer>.CreateValue() + 0x1c7 bytes 
    mscorlib.dll!System.Lazy<Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer>.LazyInitValue() + 0x1dc bytes   
    MvcApi.dll!MvcApi.App_Start.UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer() + 0x47 bytes   
    MvcApi.dll!MvcApi.App_Start.UnityWebApiActivator.Start() + 0x28 bytes   
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    WebActivatorEx.dll!WebActivatorEx.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod() + 0x155 bytes    
    WebActivatorEx.dll!WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods<WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute>(bool designerMode) + 0x356 bytes    
    WebActivatorEx.dll!WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunPreStartMethods(bool designerMode) + 0x2f bytes  
    WebActivatorEx.dll!WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.Run() + 0xbd bytes  
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Reflection.MethodInfo> methods, System.Func<System.IDisposable> setHostingEnvironmentCultures) + 0x1a5 bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Reflection.MethodInfo> methods) + 0x67 bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(string preStartInitListPath) + 0xf0 bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() + 0x98 bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager appManager, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Configuration.IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, System.Security.Policy.PolicyLevel policyLevel, System.Exception appDomainCreationException) + 0x47f bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager appManager, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Configuration.IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, System.Security.Policy.PolicyLevel policyLevel) + 0x26 bytes 
    [Appdomain Transition]  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(string appId, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) + 0x147d bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(string appId, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) + 0x35 bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.GetAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(string appId, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) + 0x92 bytes  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateObjectInternal(string appId, System.Type type, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, bool failIfExists, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) + 0x6f bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ProcessHost.StartApplication(string appId, string appPath, out object runtimeInterface) + 0x1fb bytes
```

Comment: There hasn't been any copy pasta between these projects in which you included the wrong namespace/forgot to update a namespace has there?

Comment: @Tommy I've checked for pasta, and can't find any! It will be embarrassing if it turns up somewhere

Comment: @Baconbeastnz, does MvcAdmin have a reference to MvcApi?  Based on the names I'd like to assume MvcAdmin is consuming MvcApi. If this is the case the PreApplicationStartMethod attribute is applied to both assemblies than the PreApplicationStartMethod  targets on both assemblies will be called.  MSDN states, "There is no guarantee of the order in which the assembly-defined application start methods are called.".

Answer (score 2):

So I think ther dll/assemblies from the various projects must be in that sites folder. Part of WebActivatorEx's start-up is to scan all assemblies for the assembly-level WebActivatorEx PreApplicationStartMethod and ApplicationShutdownMethod attributes and fire up any classes they reference.

This could well mean a dll/assembly intended for another project gets started up simply because it's in the wrong place.

Ideally those assemblies just wouldn't be there - they aren't by default in a web publish process - but Azure deployment via git etc. could cause them to be.